# How can I make histogram from classes in data.frame in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use the code below to make a frequency table with classes.

```
MyDF <- data.frame(MyCl = c("[1,2)", "[1,2)", "[1,2)"), 
                   ClFreq = c(3, 7, 2))
```

I wanted to make a histogram from this data, but I could't find a solution.

An ugly solution was to make a barplot from this `data.frame`, so I tried this code:

```
library(ggplot2)

WrongHist <- ggplot(data=MyDF, aes(x=MyCl, y=ClFreq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") 

WrongHist
```

But the result was a barplot with only one bar.

1. **What am I doing wrong with the barplot?**
2. **Can I make a real histogram (not a barplot) from this `data.frame`?**

Comment: MyCl is a character vector. how is r supposed to draw this? `x11()
hist(MyDF$ClFreq)` gives a histogram but i am not sure if this is what you want. could you maybe elaborate?

Comment: The column `MyCl` is a constant. Therefore `geom_bar` will set each `ClFreq` over each other. You should add an expected result. Like this it is not clear what your expectations are.

Comment: The answers to your two questions are 1) You have all the same categories in `MyCl` (they are all "[1,2)") so they all appear at the same point on the x axis, giving you a single bar. If you want them in different positions on the x axis, you need to specify what the x axis represents. Maybe a different column like `variable = c("A", "B", "C")`. 2) No, you can't make a histogram from this data. A histogram takes a single continuous variable and splits it into "bins", then counts how many entries there are in each bin. If `MyCl` had different ranges you could reconstruct a histogram though.

Comment: @Edo , thanks a lot... I 'm so stupid. I forgot to change the intervals' boundaries... The code was `MyDF <- data.frame(MyCl=c("[1,2)","[2,3)","[3,4)"), ClFreq=c(3,7,2))`. Sorry for bothering you...

Comment: @AllanCameron thanks for both of your answers! The first question was by mistake... I didn't notice that I had the same interval. I wanted `MyDF <- data.frame(MyCl=c("[1,2)","[2,3)","[3,4)"), ClFreq=c(3,7,2))`. Even with that changes there is no solution for question 2. Am I wrong?

Comment: `MyCl` is a character variable, therefore a barplot is the correct solution. You could use a histogram if you had a numeric variable. I suspect that `MyCl` is the output of the function `cut`. If you don't use `cut`, you can define a histogram. On the histogram you can define intervals (`breaks`) for the x axis. Share your initial data. We can help you with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the extra information supplied in the comments, we can reverse-engineer the original data from `MyDF` well enough to create a histogram with ggplot2:

```r
MyDF <- data.frame(MyCl = c(rep(1.5, 3), rep(2.5, 7), rep(3.5, 2)))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(MyDF, aes(MyCl)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks = 1:4, color = "black", fill = "dodgerblue")
```

[image]

Comment: excellent. Thank's a lot. Sorry for bothering you... Should I change the first question?

Comment: @KώσταςΚούδας no, I think the chain of comments explain the process well here.